# Can Civirules differentiate between 'pending' and 'added' group status?

Tags: groups, civirules, tags, pending

I'm using Civirules to assign tags to members who add themselves to a group via public webform using the Linked Trigger 'Contact is added to group,' but the group requires double opt-in. Civirules doesn't seem to differentiate between group status types, so the tag is immediately applied to all 'pending' members even before the member has confirmed via the link in their email. Is there a way for Civirules to recognize the difference between 'pending' and 'added,' and only apply an action when one's group status is 'added'?

Comment: Could you use a CiviRule based on them having fired through the opt-in - not sure how that is recorded. inbound email? or does it only get recorded by changing Group member status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a *Field Value Comparison* condition.  This lets you only fire the rule if a field has a certain value.

For *Condition Parameters* set the following values:

*Entity*: **GroupContact**
*Field*: **Group Contact Status**
*Operator*: **is equal to**
*Compare value*:**Added**

Comment: This was the perfect solution, I wasn't aware of the Field Value Comparison condition. Many thanks, Jon!

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround could you create a smart group for everyone added to the group (not pending) and use that for your CiviRule?

Comment: Smart Groups don't work with CiviRules, sadly